# Permission denied on unzipped file (popen)

Tags: c++, bash, unix

I am trying to auto-execute zipped script sent from server to client.

Assume I have script "script.sh":

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/my_file.txt
```

I executed `chmod 777 script.sh` just to make sure it will have all the rights everywhere.

After that, I zipped it into `package.zip`

When requested by client, server will encode *package.zip* into base64, send it via xml to client, and client will decode it back into *package.zip* and save.

After that, it is unzipped and client tries to execute it with *popen*. All I get is: `Permission Denied for script.sh`

When I zip and unzip back original zip, all rights are set **as before**, **777**.

But **after sending** data to client, rights are: **-rw-rw-r--** (which makes sense why it can't be executed)

**Using POCO lib decompres**

Comment: How is it unzipped? You need to unzip it using a library/program that respects UNIX file permisisons.

Comment: It is unzipped by Poco library

Comment: A quick look at [the source code](http://poco.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/poco/poco/trunk/Zip/src/Decompress.cpp?revision=981&view=markup&pathrev=1049) confirms that the Poco zip library does not try to restore unix permissions on files.

Comment: May I ask then, what tool should I use for that?

Comment: You say you tested it and found that the permissions were preserved in your test; you can use that tool.

Comment: I kinda refuse to go back to system calls. Would like to use c++ lib

Comment: Unfortunately, asking to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". It shouldn't be too hard to find a suitable library now that you know what the problem is (if you go tadman's tar.gz route, you'll be more likely to find suitable libraries since .tar.gz is a pure unix format, and not a dos format with optional unix permissions on top)

Comment: @Gelidus Don't be so upset about system calls. UNIX is *all about* system calls. The entire thing is designed to make it easy to pipe data from one process to another for whatever reason.

Comment: @thatotherguy link you posted to the source code is 6 years old. Here is new one https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Zip/src/Decompress.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip files are not required to encode permissions. If you want that sort of thing you need a `tar` file, as that format does have a way of encoding that data. The standard way to do this is `tar.gz` or `tar.bz`.

Comment: I thought, if I unzip it and it has the correct rights, they should be also sent. Is this false?

Comment: @Gelidus: no. zip dates back to msdos, and the ONLY permission bits it encodes are msdos "permissions": archive/readonly/hidden/system bits. there's no provision for any kind of modern permission options (e.g. unix/ntfs user stuff). if you want to store unix permission bits, then you can't use zip. it's that simple.

Comment: @marcb Exactly. We're lucky .zip files can handle filenames longer than 8 letters and extensions longer than 3! There's been extensions to the standard added to the format over the years to accommodate longer filenames. As far as I know, there's no standard for encoding permissions.

Comment: @tadman: that's because zip was extended to support fat32 semantics when Win95 came out. Other than adding a few compression and encryption algorithms, I don't think the zip format has had any fundamental changes since then.